# How to click a view behind a button in Android?

Tags: android, events, touch

I want to create a shape or button but when it is clicked it will send the event to the view behind of it. 
I've used the onInterceptTouchEvent but still the event is taken by the button instead of the View.
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:background="@drawable/background">

 <com.Example.MultitouchView
          android:id="@+id/touchView"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#FF0000" />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#110342" >
</Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

MultitouchView.class

```
public class MultitouchView extends View {

private boolean isMultiTouch = false;
private static final int        SWIPE_MIN_LENGHT        = 100;
private static final long       MULTITOUCH_DELAY        = 500;
private long    mTouchStart;

public MultitouchView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public MultitouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
          super(context, attrs, defStyle);

  }

  public MultitouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
          super(context, attrs);

  }

  public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getContext(), "TEST", 1000);
    toast.show();

    return false;

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                Log.d("MultitouchExample","Action Down");
                mTouchStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
                SoundManager.playSound(1,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to setOnclickListener() programmatically on your Button component, then return false on the onClick method. This makes the onClick event go through and continue to other component behind?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
    public boolean hasWindowFocus() {
            return isEnabled() && getVisibility() == VISIBLE ? true : false;
        }
```

in your MultiTouchView class.
I hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You should extend Button and return false in Button.onTouchEvent()

```
new Button(dozActivity) {
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    return false;
}
};
```

or notify the OnTouchListener of the View behind the button:

Comment: The button is not working, I've created the ButtonDummy with the onTouchEvent returning false but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem adding this in the button:

android:clickable="false"

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Rectangle variable right on the sizes and position of your button and use it like;

```
If(touch != null && rectangle.contains(touchPoint))
{
    // do action      
}
```

If you update this before updating your button, the rectangle will be your new invisible button.